# BackboneJs: In a view whats the difference between el: and tagName:

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around this concept.

Can you dumb this down for me and maybe provide a simple example of the difference between the `el:` attribute and the `tagName:` attribute?

In some examples, different views use `el:` sometimes and others use `tagName:`.

I'm specifically messing around with my own implementation of this [example](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/4.html)

Comment: el will reference to existing elements in our DOM, while tagName we will create a new dom element with the tagName with className if given.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is this:

el should be used to preserve a reference to the actual DOM node representing the view as a whole.

This means you can easily perform actions on it with jQuery or w/e.  $(this.el).hide() or $(this.el).html('I am a Jquery Object now');

TagName is only a string that is used to determine the type of DOM node el will be.  The default is div, but if you wanted, you could make it any HTML element you please.

Consider:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html('I am a jQuery-ized paragraph');
        return this;
    }
});


$(document.body).append(new view().render().el);
```

The problem you might be running into is that sometimes you set el on the instantiation of a view, in which case the tagName is irrelevant:

```
var myView = new view({ el: $("someExistingEl") });
```

Comment: So they are never used together?

Comment: they can't be used together. if you specify an `el` directly, your `tagName` will be ignored.

Comment: They can be used together, you just can't explicitly set this.el = $(somethingelse) and expect it to honor this.tagName.  If you do use $(this.el).html('some stuff'), it will be inside whatever this.tagName is.

Comment: It's probably me, but it's not clear to me why to use tagname: 'p' instead of el: 'p' in the example...

Comment: @KimGysen What happens if you swap the `tagName` for an `el` property and set your `el` to an element that doesn't exist on the DOM (i.e assume there are no `p` tags on the page)?

Comment: Thanks, it has become very clear by now. It took some time to get started, but it turns out to be great now.

Comment: @SkylarAnderson: Kindly provide an example related to usage of both. Like where I can use el and where I can go with tagname. It will be really helpful to novice like me.

Answer (score -3):

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  id: 'identity',
  class: 'classy',
  el: $(this.tagName), // or
  el: $('<' + this.tagName + ' />', {
    id: this.id,       // identity
    'class': this.class  // classy
  })  // this is jQuery shorthand for building an element fyi
});

var view = new View();
```

I think that should work fine.

Comment: `this` in `el: $(this.tagName)` won't be what you think it is.