# Difference between el and tagname in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone and I am not able to understand the difference between el and tagname. I looked into this [BackboneJs: In a view whats the difference between el: and tagName:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432560/backbonejs-in-a-view-whats-the-difference-between-el-and-tagname) . But I could not understand.

Below is what I have till now.

**Script Example:**

```
     // Vehicle Model
        var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend(
        {
            idAttribute: "registrationNumber",
            urlRoot: "/api/vehicles",
            validate: function(attrs)
            {
                if(!attrs.registrationNumber)
                    return "Vehicle without reistration";

            }
        });

        // Vehicle Collection
        var Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend(
        {
            model: Vehicle
        });

        // Vehicle View
        var VehicleView = Backbone.View.extend(
        {
            tagName: "li",
//*******************************************************
    // el: "li" **THIS DOES NOT WORK!!
//**********************************************************
            render: function ()
            {
                var source = $("#vehicleTemplate").html();
                var template = _.template(source);
                this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        // Vehicle View for collection
        var VehiclesView = Backbone.View.extend({
            render: function() {
                var self = this;
                this.collection.each(function(vehicle) {
                    var vehicleView = new VehicleView({
                        model: vehicle
                    });
                    self.$el.append(vehicleView.render().$el);
                });
            }
        });

        // creating collection
        var vehicles = new Vehicles(
            [
                new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "ABCD1234"}),
                new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "ABCD5678"}),
                new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "DCBA1234"}),
                new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "DCBA1423"})
            ]);

        // instance for vehicles View
        var vehiclesView = new VehiclesView({collection: vehicles, el: "#vehicleAnchor"});
        vehiclesView.render();
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

        <script src="js/lib/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id = "vehicleAnchor">
    </ul>
        <script src="js/lib/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <script id = "vehicleTemplate" type = "text/html">
       <%= registrationNumber%>
        </script>
         <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine but when I replace `tagName with el`, it stops working Why please guide me in layman language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://backbonejs.org/#View-el), the `el` property is used as a reference to the DOM element, whereas the tagName is used when creating an element.

This means that when you specify a string as the `el` it will look in the existing DOM tree (basically your HTML) for an element that matches that selector (it will function as a jquery selector). Since you do not have an `li` element in your markup, the `el` will be null and the view will be unable to initialize.

When you are using the tagName on the other hand, backbone automatically  uses that to create a new element and assign it to the `el` property.
Be aware however, that the newly created element must then be added to the DOM. This is what you do in `VehiclesView` with the line `self.$el.append(vehicleView.render().$el);`

Comment: "Be aware however, that the newly created element must then be added to the DOM" : as you told tagName is more like a string and when it gets added in the DOM it gets its logical meaning. So its essential to add it in the DOM. Am I right?

Comment: tagName is simply the html element you want the view to become. Be it `div` (default tagname is div), or `li` or `header`, or `table`. Any valid html element can be a tagName.

Comment: Unbreakable: You are not as such adding the tagName to the DOM. As Eric write, it is used to determine the type of the element that will be created. What you are adding will still be the el. And the el object will have all the same logic as any other DOM element, but it won't be rendered anywhere until it is added to the DOM